# JSON from JS to View in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, json

I'm new in json, javascript, and django, and I don't exactly understand how it works. I'm working on a web application and I want to know how to pass data from a template to a view. I know that for this I must use javascript and json. So when in JS script I type, for example, `var a = "Hello world"` how do I pass it a different string from the django view to the variable `a` in the javascript for the page on the browser?

Please help me with this with a simple example or link.

Comment: I googled but didn't find an exact example

Comment: upvote @mariodev's answer. looks like it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is kinda broad question to begin with. You can pass variables in different ways using ajax, it all depend what kind of data you're providing, for simple variables you can use something like this:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    url(r'^call/ajax/$', 'myapp.views.home_ajax', name='home-ajax'),
)
```

views.py

```
def home_ajax(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        my_var = request.GET.get('myvar')
        return HttpResponse('ajax called with myvar: %s' % my_var)

    return HttpResponse()
```

template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var myVar = 'durr';
  $.get("{% url 'home-ajax' %}", {myvar: myVar}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
</script>
```